addEventListener() for touch screens
I do Etch-a-Sketch.
It is one of the functions. It work normally on computer with mouse. But don't work on touch screens (phone).
mouseSquares.forEach(gridSquares => {

        gridSquares.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
            
            if (mouseHoveringColor === "yellow") {
                gridSquares.style.backgroundColor = mouseBackgroundColor;   
            } else if (mouseHoveringColor === "randomize") {
                gridSquares.style.backgroundColor = mouseBackgroundColor;
            } else {
                let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                let g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                let b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
                gridSquares.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
            }

        });

        gridSquares.addEventListener('click', () => {
            gridSquares.style.backgroundColor = SQUARESBACKGROUNDCOLOR;
        });

    });

I tried add events touchmove and touchcancel - but it doesn't work too.
I need both functionality: for computer mouse and for touch screens.

I have problem with work on touch screens, NOT with computer mouse. I need both functionality.

@OlKlym Please read the answers to the question. It's actually relevant to what solutions you are looking for and will explain to you how you can have both.

I tried add events touchmove and touchcancel - but it doesn't work too. perhaps you did it wrong ... the code you've shown shows no attempt to troubleshoot your issue

I STRONGLY suggest you delegate from the container instead of looping

Are you sure it doesn’t work? I tested the ‘click’ event, and it works on both mobile phones and computer mouse clicks. Perhaps the issue is related to gridSquares variable. In general, you can test this function to ensure it works correctly on touchscreens:
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {     console.log("touch"); });

I am sure. I tested on computer and my phone (from my site on github.io). On phone it doesn't work.



perhaps you did it wrong ... the code you've shown shows no attempt to troubleshoot your issue>> I changed mouseover and click - on touchmove and touchcancel


